# Error with nullable Double PathParam

Tags: java, web-services, jersey

I have a REST service:

```
@POST
@Path("/shop/{prodID}/{price}")
public Response updatePrice(@PathParam("prodID") Long prodID, @PathParam("price") Double price) {
        priceDAO.updatePrice(prodID, price);
        return Response.ok().build();
}
```

If i send number for UI they work great, but if a send empty param (null) I have error:

```
sitesurl/shop/33/null 404 Not Found
```

and

```
Class java.lang.Double can not be instantiated using a constructor with a single String argument
```

on console.

If null sending as string ("null") we could see NumberFormatException.

Why my service can not parse nullable PathParam?

Comment: What happens if you just don't have anything there at all? (Note also that for an update, you really should be including the price as a form element rather than a path parameter.)

Comment: I send request after updating any cell form grid. For example, I have a grid with prodName, other columns, price - user edit price for prod with id 33, and I send and update only price for this product.I have service for any grid columns: updatePrice, updateName, updateLocation and etc...

Answer (score 0):

chrylis if you dont provide any of the path params it would throw a 404 resource not found,

I Agree with Chrylis form param would be a good idea.
Gene then you should ensure while sending the request path params are not null and complying to the resource specifications. for a Long or a double string should not be sent.
Another way of getting rid is you keep the resource spec as String, and manually cast to Long etc..
There is way to handle ParamExcption well. Create a Mapper that implements ExceptionMapper and throw your custom response